# Add keyboard shortcut to this code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> as keyboard shortcut for that submenu button EXIT...
I'm a very beginner here and I would be grateful for added code and explanation.

```
    #RPi_CPC GUI
from Tkinter import *
from subprocess import call
import subprocess as sub
import os
import sys

#create the window
root = Tk()
root.configure(background="black")
#root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

#MENU FUNCTIONS
def shutdown():
 call (["poweroff"]);
def reboot():
 call (["reboot"]);
def exit():
 quit();

#MENU###################
menu = Menu(root, bg="black", fg='chartreuse')
root.config(menu=menu)
subMenu = Menu(menu, bg="black", fg='red')
menu.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="POWER OFF", font="Courier 15 bold ", command=shutdown)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="RESTART RPI!", font="Courier 15 bold", command=reboot)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="EXIT", font="Courier 15 bold ", command=exit)
subMenu.add_separator()

########################
```

Comment: Have you tried `root.bind('<Control-q>', exit)`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use

```
root.bind('<Control-q>', exit)
```

But `bind` executes function with argument `event` so you have to change your function

```
def exit(event=None):
    quit()
```

and now it will work with `bind()` and `command=`.

You can add information to menu using `accelerator=`

```
subMenu.add_command(label="EXIT", command=exit, accelerator="Ctrl+Q")
```